# in python language create several variables in a loop and after append items in each ones

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I'm trying to find a way to append items in variables created on the fly

```
c = ('a','b','g','d','j')
p = 2

for r in c:
    globals()['ssvar%s' % r] = []

for z in range (0,10,1):
    for r in c:
        p = p + 2
        (['ssvar%s' % r]).append (p)
        
    print ssvara        #result     >>> []
    print ssvarb        #result     >>> []
    print ssvarg        #result     >>> []
    print ssvard        #result     >>> []
    print ssvarj        #result     >>> []
```

but the expression (['ssvar%s' % poire]).append doesn't work.
can you direct me to the same topic or tell me how to vary the variable name to be fill ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `globals()[f'ssvar{r}'] = []`. Also `globals()[f'ssvar{r}'].append(p)` might be what you want instead of `(['ssvar%s' % r]).append (p)`.

Comment: Not that I recommend using `globals()` the way it is being used.

Comment: **don't dynamically create variables**. It is always a bad design choice

Comment: In any case, you seem to already know how to use a string to get to a global variable using `globals()`, so why did you thinkg `(['ssvar%s' % poire]).append` would work? `(['ssvar%s' % poire])` just creates a list with a single string in it... again, how did you access the global variable already .... But again, **don't do this**

Comment: Oh, and you really shouldnt be using Python 2

Comment: Oo, I just realized I used f-strings when this is clearly not Python 3.

Comment: Don't  create variables this way. It's unnecessary and fragile, creates a minefield of bugs, and is impossible to maintain.  Start with `ssvar = [ ]`.  Then, inside the loop, do `ssvar.append(p)`. As a side note, it appears that you are writing in Python 2. As a beginner, you should *not* be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of us who still work in it do so because we have to support or migrate legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** do this, but I think what you were looking to do is

```
c = ('a','b','g','d','j')
p = 2

for r in c:
    globals()['ssvar%s' % r] = []

for z in range (0, 10, 1):
    for r in c:
        p = p + 2
        globals()['ssvar%s' % r].append(p)
```

Instead, you can create your own **dictionary** (container of `key: value` pairs) and store the lists in there as values and use the keys as names. If this dictionary is called `my_dict`, then `my_dict['ssvara']` references the list corresponding to `'ssvara'`, `my_dict['ssvarb']` references the list corresponding to `'ssvarb'` and so on.

```
c = ('a','b','g','d','j')
p = 2

my_dict = {}
for r in c:
    my_dict['ssvar%s' % r] = []

for z in range (0, 10, 1):
    for r in c:
        p = p + 2
        my_dict['ssvar%s' % r].append(p)

print my_dict
```

Output

```
{'ssvara': [4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94],
 'ssvarb': [6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96],
 'ssvard': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
 'ssvarg': [8, 18, 28, 38, 48, 58, 68, 78, 88, 98],
 'ssvarj': [12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92, 102]}
```

If the actual names are not important (you are, after all, creating them dynamically), you can just create a **list** of lists. If this list is called `my_list`, `my_list[0]` references the first sublist, `my_list[1]` references the second, and so on.

```
c = ('a','b','g','d','j')
p = 2

my_list = [[] for i in range(len(c))]

for z in range (0, 10, 1):
    for l in my_list:
        p = p + 2
        l.append(p)

print my_list
```

Output

```
[[4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94],
 [6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96],
 [8, 18, 28, 38, 48, 58, 68, 78, 88, 98],
 [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
 [12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92, 102]]
```

I don't use Python 2 so I had to make a few interpolations.

Answer (score 0):

I try to create temporaly variables with multiple items inside.
in fact I need to have, for exemple, this result:

```
ssvara
>>>> ['4','6','8','10','12','14','16', '8','20','22']
ssvara
>>>> ['24','26','28','30','32','34','36', '38','40','42']
```

the value of p is not important, the main thing is to be able to append. even with a local variable.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?